# In Rails 3, how do I implement breadcrumbs with multiple paths to nodes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, breadcrumbs

In our application, various articles can be reached via a number of paths.

You could, for example, go 
`"home > category 'rock music' > article 'Behind the Beatles'"`,

or `"home > category 'pop music' > article 'Behind the Beatles'"`,

or even `"home > magazine > series 'background' > article 'Behind the Beatles'"`

and reach the same article every time.

I'm guessing I need to save the path the user takes in the session, and push / pop individual elements, but I'm hoping someone somewhere already has a working solution.

I checked out the following gems already: crummy, breadcrumbs-on-rails and gretel, and (barring me misunderstanding the documention) they all seem to expect a single path to a node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you don't do what you are proposing. Search engines recognise breadcrumbs (with use of proper tags). What you're talking about sounds more like related navigable content 'See also...'.

If you decide this is really what you want to do, have separate routes and noindex tags on one of the pages.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I hope I can talk our customer out of it.

Would your answer have been any different if I hadn't used the word "breadcrumb", and instead talked about a "user trail" or something?

Comment: It's important to have a clear and consistent site structure. Search engines may rank you down if it believes your site to be otherwise and your bounce rate may increase if people don't recognise well established web conventions. I think a user trail implementation is a good idea but should follow the convention of 'recently viewed' or 'see also' navigation.